# Método setGravity() do Toast não funciona na API Level 30

Tags: android, kotlin, toasts

Estou tentando exibir uma mensagem de *Toast* no topo de uma *Activity* comum, ao clicar em um *Button*, utilizando o método `setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)` na *API Level* 30 (*release* R), no entanto não está funcionando. O trecho original, em *Kotlin*, seria o seguinte:

```kotlin
val toast = Toast.makeText(
                this,
                R.string.correct_toast,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
            toast.show()
```

Na *API Level* 29 (*release* Q) funciona normalmente. Olhando na documentação, (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/Toast#setgravity), me deparei com um *warning* falando que o *Toast.setGravity* está como *no-op* em *API Build.VERSION_CODES#R*. Não entendi muito bem o que essa *Build.VERSION_CODES#R* quer dizer, mas aparentemente não parece funcionar em *Build* mais nova (especificamente na *Level* 30). Como poderia contornar isso, usando a *API Level 30*? Ou realmente nas *Build* mais novas não tem como usar mais o *setGravity*?

O warning mencionado acima:

> Warning: Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#R, for apps
> targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R or higher, this method is a
> no-op when called on text toasts.

Answer (score 0):

Muitas vezes esta mudança está indicando que é legal trocar o toast por snackbar, como:

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(layout, message, duration)
    val snackbarLayout: View = snackbar.view
    val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    lp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0)
    
    snackbarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp)
    snackbar.show()
```

snackbarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
snackbar.show();